# DynamoDB Collection(s) Model

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am learning how to model a NoSQL databases and trying to understand how to make this works properly.

For my use case I have spin up a local instance of aws dynamo db and connected successfully.

Now, let's say I have two contexts **"Users"** and **"Groups"**, where one user can belong to any group, and one group can have multiple users. I am trying to avoid multiple collections but I cannot see the way to.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
{    
     name: "Bob Smith",    
     dob: "1980-01-01     
     groups: [
          {
               name: "Sports"
               CreatedAt: "2022-01-05"
          }.
          {
               name: "Arts"
               CreatedAt: "2022-01-08"
          }
     ]
}
```

What I am not sure is what should we do if I need to create or update a Group? if I follow the previous pattern, how would be the query for the groups?

Shall I have 2 collections?

Thanks guys for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically only hold a pointer to the groups within a users item, if you need to update the group details then you would do so in the item for the group.

| pk | sk | groups | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | USER#user123 | groups[{pk:group1, sk: GROUP#group1}, {pk:group3, sk: GROUP#group3}] | user data |
| user009 | USER#user009 | groups[{pk:group5, sk: GROUP#group5}, {pk:group7, sk: GROUP#group7}] | user data |
| group1 | GROUP#group1 |  | group-info thats editable |
| group3 | GROUP#group3 |  | group-info thats editable |
| group5 | GROUP#group5 |  | group-info thats editable |
| group7 | GROUP#group7 |  | group-info thats editable |

Of course this is not the only way to do this, but with all things NoSQL it totally depends on your access patterns. For example, if you have a requirement to get all users for a given group then you would need to change the above schema:

| pk | sk | other | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | USER#user123 | user-data |  |
| user123 | GROUP#group1 |  | some data |
| user123 | GROUP#group3 |  | some data |
| group1 | GROUP#group1 | group data |  |
| group3 | GROUP#group3 | group data |  |

Now you can get all the groups a user belongs to by issuing a `Query` stating:

`pk=user123 AND sk BEGINS_WITH(GROUP#)`.

Then use a Global Secondary Index to get all the users which belong to a given group, with `sk` being your GSI's partition key:

`gsi_pk = GROUP#group1`

Comment: Thanks @Lee for your reply. The second way it starts making more sense to me. What about if I would need to do it in the 2 ways: All groups that the user belongs to AND/OR all users that a specific group has. you mentioned `pk=user123 AND sk BEGINS_WITH(GROUP#)` for all the groups by a given user, how do I get all the users by a given group?

Comment: You use a Global Secondary Index with the SK from the main table as the PK of the GSI, I explain this at the end.